# How to select distinct column from my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

I have two tables that I work with. The first table `#CustomerList` I manually initialize with values. Then I create a second table `#CustomerListWithRank_Id` that is based on the first first table `#CustomerList`.

The only different between the first and second table is that the second table `#CustomerListWithRank_Id` has a column that gives each row it's rownumber which I use further down in my SQL code when I loop through that table.

So the problem that I have is that I just want to initialize `#CustomerListWithRank_Id` with only unique values from the column [FileName], how do I do that?

```
SELECT '3004' Customer_No,'831001' DDD_Reference_No,'varer831.csv' [FileName]
INTO #CustomerList -- DROP TABLE #CustomerList
UNION ALL SELECT '3002' Customer_No,'199001' DDD_Reference_No,'varer199.csv' [FileName]
UNION ALL SELECT '3003' Customer_No,'199002' DDD_Reference_No,'varer199.csv' [FileName]
```

-

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Customer_No) AS 'Rank_Id'
INTO #CustomerListWithRank_Id --DROP TABLE #CUstomerListWithRank_ID
FROM #CustomerList
```

If I use GROUP BY [FileName] in the query above I get this error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column '#CustomerList.Customer_No' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Customer_No) AS 'Rank_Id'
INTO #CustomerListWithRank_Id 
from
(
    SELECT max(Customer_No) Customer_No, max(DDD_Reference_No) DDD_Reference_No, FileName
    FROM #CustomerList
    group by FileName
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need

```
SELECT * INTO #CustomerListWithRank_Id From
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileName Order by Customer_No)  AS RowNum FROM CustomerList)
```